# Eclipse: My SSH key does not match the SSH key associated with my Heroku Acct

Tags: eclipse, heroku

I get this error when I try to create new project via "Create Heroku App Template", however, I can successfully see the application deployed in my heroku acct.

```
    We have encountered a problem creating your application: arcane-citadel-9718. This could be due to the Eclipse SSH key is not matching the SSH key(s) that is associated with your Heroku account. To fix this error, you can: - Associate your SSH key to your Heroku account by going to "Preferences" OR - If the SSH Key is correct, restart Eclipse.
git@heroku.com:arcane-citadel-9718.git: reject HostKey: heroku.com
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: well, using the same SSH keys? do you have some issue doing so?

Comment: had the same issue ,

This Thread solved my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374030/eclipse-my-ssh-key-does-not-match-the-ssh-key-associated-with-my-heroku-acct

Comment: had the same issue ,

This Thread solved my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374030/eclipse-my-ssh-key-does-not-match-the-ssh-key-associated-with-my-heroku-acct

Answer (score 1):

I Have found the solution. I created an environment variable `GIT_SSH` which points to `usr/bin/ssh` with `export GIT_SSH=usr/bin/ssh`, then run eclpse from terminal. Then import or create new heroku application.

Comment: Thank you , solved my problem ! :) 

btw . .how did you figure this out ?

Answer (score 1):

Trick: add the git-repo manually in eclipse, e.g.:  git@heroku.com:your-app
eclipse eGit then will add the key to known hosts somewhere. cancel the git clone and go back to "import heroku app". It will work.

Comment: I don't know why someone down-voted Rémy, but this worked for me and the other answers didn't.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the git repository is hosted somewhere else. The trick is to add its IP to the known hosts. This is done automatically when cloning your app via the terminal, e.g.

```
git clone git@heroku.com:myappname.git
```

Then you should also be able to import it with Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Visit this - [Resolve Error : Eclipse SSH key is not matching the SSH key(s) that is associated with your Heroku account](http://www.shivasoft.in/blog/others/tips/resolve-error-eclipse-ssh-key-is-not-matching-the-ssh-keys-that-is-associated-with-your-heroku-account/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SSH is rejecting the server-side keys for Heroku.

Try running `ssh git@heroku.com` from your terminal to accept Heroku's host key.

Comment: I get `shell request failed on channel 0`

Comment: That sounds like you are able to connect to Heroku via SSH. (You're getting the error because Heroku doesn't provide shell access via SSH). Does pushing with Eclipse work after connecting with SSH? Does pushing work by running `git push heroku master` from your command line?

Comment: I SSH to a t1.micro instance of ubuntu 12.04in AWS in eclipse using remote system explorer then tried 'git push heroku master' which works. I use the same SSH keys that I generated in the CLI in eclipse.

Comment: I tried creating a new Heroku account and a fresh install of eclipse. I followed the instructions in [link]https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-heroku-eclipse but still to no avail.

Comment: Try to SSH to Heroku using the remote system explorer in Eclipse. Use the username `git` and the private key you generated for your Heroku account.

Comment: I was able to solve it by cloning one my heroku apps to my local machine. I dont understand why it solved the problem though.